# How to get new Enum with members as enum using EnumMeta Python 3.6

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying translate some code from python 2 to python 3 and had trouble with this code:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta


class KeyCode(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3


class KeyMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        dct.update({e.name: e.value for e in KeyCode})
        return super(KeyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)


class Key(Enum, metaclass=KeyMeta):
    pass


print(repr(Key.A))
```

The problem is that for python2 `Key.A` is `enum < Key.A: 1>`, whereas for python3 it is `< class 'int'>`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Having the same set of names in several different `Enum`s?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42253518/208880) could help with that.  Also, see [When should I subclass EnumMeta instead of Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880) for some good general advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, the `dct` object is not a regular dictionary, but a subclass dedicated to helping create enums, set via the [`__prepare__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace) of the metaclass. It's `update()` method, however, is not altered from the base dictionary.

It normally expects members to be set via it's [`__setitem__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/84c36c152a2bdf98f9cc7ce0e1db98e1f442a05e/Lib/enum.py#L64-L108) (e.g. `dct[name] = value`); do so in your `__new__` method too:

```
class KeyMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        for e in KeyCode:
            dct[e.name] = e.value
        return super(KeyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
```

Now each of the names `A`, `B` and `C` are recorded as being enum member names and the `EnumMeta` class takes it from there. Without using the specialised `__setitem__` implementation, the names are seen as some other type of attribute instead.

With the above change you get the expected output:

```
>>> class Key(Enum, metaclass=KeyMeta):
...     pass
...
>>> Key.A
<Key.A: 1>
```

The same `for e in KeyCode:` loop will continue to work in Python 2 as well.